# Helm pass values to the templates for multiple environment

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am very newbie on Helm and struggling to configure deployment.yaml.Mychart tree structure looks like below. But how should I pass the values for dev and prod to the deployment.yaml?

For example if I would like to use different replicas for prod should I add another values such as below or deployment.yaml always keep as it is and use mutlipe values.yaml like as below.

```
 replicas: {{ .Values.replicaCount .values.dev.replicacount }}
```

Or use only below tag is enough. Let's say if git branch equals to master then use below command

```
helm install . -f values.production.yaml
```

If git branch equal to development then use following command

```
 helm install . -f values.dev.yaml


+-- charts
|   \-- my-chart
|       +-- Chart.yaml        # Helm chart metadata
|       +-- templates
|       |   \-- ...
|       +-- values.yaml       # default values
|       +-- values.dev.yaml   # development override values
|       +-- values.prod.yaml  # production override values
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a `values.yaml` file per environment.

That means that in your `templates/deployment.yaml` you'll have

```
 replicas: {{ .Values.replicaCount }}
```

And then, for each environment you'll have a specific `values.yaml`. Like:

```
+-- values.yaml       # default values
+-- values.dev.yaml   # development override values
+-- values.prod.yaml  # production override values
```

Comment: So use helm install . -f values.prod.yaml command in Jenkins according to the git branch is cover what I want , am I correct?

Comment: You can keep different `values.yaml` in separate branches or in the same branch with different suffixes. I would say the second option is used more often. It's like in the Spring Boot app, you usually keep configuration files for different environments in the same branch, but distinguish them by the suffix.

Comment: Could you please share a small examples for second option?

Comment: The second option is exactly what you have in your listing. In the main directory, in the master branch, you have all configuration files for all environments: `values.yaml`, `values.dev.yaml`, `values.prod.yaml`.

Comment: And how does helm know which one to use?

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on the differences between your environments.

As being described in [helm docs](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_best_practices/values/#consider-how-users-will-use-your-values):

> There are three potential sources of values:
>
> - A chart's `values.yaml` file
> - A values file supplied by `helm install -f` or `helm upgrade -f` on `helm install` or `helm upgrade`
> - The values passed to a `--set` or `--set-string` flag

At a high level, you might want consider the two approaches below:

1. If your environments have major differences between them then passing a different `values.yaml` file is a option and worth the extra maintenance.
2. On the other hand, if the differences are only with a few fields - consider using just one base `values.yaml` file with default values and override just the specific fields with the `--set` flag.

---

(*) In your specific case, you divided the DEV/PROD configuration into different files which is a good practice but there are cases where the difference can be only with one or two urls (and maybe some secrets that you'll want to pass as inline values anyway). So you can save yourself the extra maintenance.